# How to change layout of page but same URL

Tags: html

Hi I have a basic login system for my website, its not meant to be the best and most secure but its a login page and when you enter the password it redirects to a whole different page, I would like to know how to make the page change completely
after logging in, heres the password page source.
I know it's possible, all I need is to change the entire layout when successfully logged in.

```html
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Login</TITLE>
      <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
         <!--- PASSWORD PROTECTION SCRIPT
            function AuthDetials() {
            
            var password = 'password';
            
            if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
              top.location.href="correct.html";
            }
            else {
              location.href="incorrect.html";
              }
            }
            
            
            // End hiding --->
      </script>
      <style type="text/css">
         BODY { COLOR: #FFFFFF; FONT: 12px verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal }
      </style>
```

Comment: use **ajax**  [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: thankyou, im fairly new to javascript and other website languages could I possibly get a snippet? if its to big then don't worry, I have a template to change the page to but don't know where to begin. any more help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can have say div elements hidden/shown as and when required, say your case where the login is successful then show the div else hidden. You also have addClass and removeClass functions.

Comment: Ok thankyou, your version sounds less complex, I'll look into this hiding and showing stuff, also is there a way to hide the body? because my template uses alot of div container's and tables so It'll take along time, if not Ill do it all by hand :).

Answer (score 2):

```
//demo.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>





// ajax_info.txt

hello
```

Comment: Sweet thankyou this will help alot with future projects and maybe this one! :D this site is the best for answers ASAP I thought I'd have to check back tomorrow after school for 2 views and maybe a noob reply but this is all professional grade stuff. thankyou both.